Ardurino UNO - Servo Control
I am having problem desinging ardurino code that turns mini servo acording postion of 10kOhm Potentiometer.
This is my code:
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;       // create servo object to control a servo
int potpin = 0;      // analog pin used to connect the potentiometer
int val;             // variable to read the value from the analog pin

void setup() {
 myservo.attach(9); // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop() {
    val = analogRead(potpin); // reads the value of the potentiometer (0 to 1023)

    // Map the potentiometer readings to the servo's range
    int servoPosition = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 180);

    // Ensure servo stops moving when potentiometer is at its extremes
    if (servoPosition == 0 || servoPosition == 180) {
        myservo.write(servoPosition); // sets servo position
    } else {
        myservo.write(servoPosition - 90);
    }

    delay(15); // waits for the servo to get there
}

I want that when potentiometer value is 1023 (Max) that servo turns 1 full rotation and waits there. When potentiometer value will be 0 (Min) servo will return full rotation.

the analog read value is unlikely to ever reach 0 or 1023. What you should do is establish a minValue and maxValue (which you can manually tune by reading the actual value of the potentiometer when in each of the extremes). Then use those values.

Can someone help me doing that please. I dont have a lot experience programing ardurino.

in your current code, both 0 and 180 go to the same position (180). Shouldn't a value of 0 go to position -90 and a value of 180 go to a position of +90? Why do you treat the 0 and 180 as separate cases from the other angle values?
